# Why did I failed to speed up my program by making it cache-friendly?

Tags: caching, parallel-processing, fortran, hpc

I used intel's ifort to compile my program

There are a lot nested loops like the one below

```
do i=1,imax
do j=1,jmax
if (a(i,j).ne.1) cycle
.....
.....
.....
enddo
enddo
```

as well as some loops like

```
do j=1,jmax
do i=1,imax
if (a(i,j).ne.1) cycle
.....
.....
.....
enddo
enddo
```

I noticed that Fortran stores arrays by column-major order, so I put j loop outside of i loop.

It confused me that, there seems a drop of performance.

In contrast, I tried to put i loop outsider of j loop for others loops. But there's still a performance loss, slight however

---

```
program p 
integer ::i, j, k, s
real ::a(1000,1000)

do i=1,1000
  do j=1,1000
    call random_number(a(i,j))
  enddo
enddo

do k=1,10000
  do j=1,1000
    do i=1,1000
      if (a(i,j) .ge. 111) s = s+a(i,j)
    enddo
  enddo
enddo

print *,s

end
```

ifort -fPIC -no-prec-div -O3 -xCORE-AVX2 a.f90 -o a
    time ./a
        10921820

```
real    0m2.221s
user    0m2.221s
sys     0m0.001s
```

---

```
program p 
integer ::i, j, k, s
real ::a(1000,1000)

do i=1,1000
  do j=1,1000
    call random_number(a(i,j))
  enddo
enddo

do k=1,10000
  do i=1,1000
    do j=1,1000
      if (a(i,j) .ge. 111) s = s+a(i,j)
    enddo
  enddo
enddo

print *,s

end
```

ifort -fPIC -no-prec-div -O3 -xCORE-AVX2 a.f90 -o a

```
time ./a
    10923324

real    0m4.459s
user    0m4.457s
sys     0m0.003s
```

The performance difference is stable, which may prove the optimization. However when I adapted it to my real project, I failed.

Thank you again, I'm quite new to stack overflow, thanks for your help

Comment: Hard to say without seeing any code. Best is to create a minimal working example...

Comment: Thank you haraldkl. I've just done that minimal working example (similar loop structure, same compile option). It turned out that there should have always been a performance boost, where my program haven't.

Comment: That is not a minimal example, a minimal example must be *complete* and *verifiable*. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question. Should I give any more details?

Comment: I don't understand your problem, the results are exactly as expected. The `k,j,i` order is faster as it should be. BTW, how can `a(i,j)` become `>= 111`? How is it possible that the answer is not 0?  I think it is only because you do not set `s=0` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention correctly, Fortran is column-major. This means that the column is the major index and that all columns of the matrix are stored one after the other in memory. Probably you assumed, that column-major means that looping over the column index means traversing the matrix over elements that are contiguous in memory, but this is not true. The matrix

```
| a11, a12, a13 |
| a21, a22, a23 |
| a31, a32, a33 |
```

is stored in column-major order as

```
a11, a21, a31, a12, a22, a32, a13, a23, a33
--column 1---  --column 2---  --column 3---
```

This means that when you create a two-dimensional loop in Fortran, the first index, which represents the row index, should always be the innermost to get the best performance, because then you traverse the matrix in the memory order that I wrote above. Therefore

```
do j=1,1000
    do i=1,1000
        if (a(i,j) .ge. 111) s = s + a(i,j)
    enddo
enddo
```

gives, as you found as well, the best performance.

Comment: I have always found these rows and columns very confusing. I actually remember which index is supposed to be the row and which the column by remembering that Fortran is supposed to be "column major" and not the other way round. However, I also do believe that the columns are contiguous, why do you say that they are not?

Comment: According to matrix notation the first index is the row, the second index is the column. In this example `a(1,1)` and `a(2,1)` represent the elements `a11` and `a21` in the example matrix I have put. These two elements are contiguous in memory, because the column (in matrix notation) is the major coordinate. You could reverse the reasoning and say that you want the columns to be contiguous in memory and that you use an alternative matrix notation where the first index is the column and the second the row.

Comment: I don't understand your words, but just from looking at your matrix picture and at the elements below it I see that the columns are contiguous in your example...

Comment: BTW have we met in Les Houches?

Comment: I follow this convention: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics). A row is a horizontal line in the matrix, represented by the first index, a column a vertical line, represented by the second index. The columns as a whole are indeed contiguous... The terminology remains confusing. I think we did meet there :)

Comment: @VladimirF I have rewritten the answer, because indeed it was confusing.